# Erro de imagem duplicada no salvamento!

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, imagem

Minha função que salva as imagens na pasta funciona corretamente, mas quando eu abro a pasta das fotos as imagens aparecem duplicada porem com nomes diferentes
Segue a função salvar:

```
   protected void btnSalvarImovel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (fuFotos.HasFile == false)
            lblImovel.Text = "Por favor selecione uma foto!";
        else
        {
            List<string> nomeFoto = new List<string> ();
            var arquivos = fuFotos.PostedFiles;
            foreach (var arquivo in arquivos)
            {
                string nomeArquivo = arquivo.FileName;
                fuFotos.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~") + "/Imovel/" + nomeArquivo);
                nomeFoto.Add("~/Imovel/" + nomeFoto + nomeArquivo + arquivo.FileName);
            }

            string comandoSQL = string.Format("INSERT INTO Imovel Values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}')",
                ddlCidade.SelectedItem.Value, ddlLocalizacao.SelectedItem.Value, ddlOperacao.SelectedItem.Value, ddlTipoImovel.SelectedItem.Value,
                txtTitulo.Text, txtObservacao.Text, txtValor.Text, txtQtdQuartos.Text, string.Join(",", nomeFoto));


            lblImovel.Text = "Imóvel cadastrado com sucesso!";
            ddlCidade.Text = string.Empty;
            ddlLocalizacao.Text = string.Empty;
            ddlOperacao.Text = string.Empty;
            ddlTipoImovel.Text = string.Empty;
            txtTitulo.Text = string.Empty;
            txtObservacao.Text = string.Empty;
            txtValor.Text = string.Empty;
            txtQtdQuartos.Text = string.Empty;


            try
            {
                conexaoSQL.Open();
                int teste = new SqlCommand(comandoSQL, conexaoSQL).ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                conexaoSQL.Close();
            }

            }
        }
```

A foto da pasta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo que ela deveria ter ficado assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu reparei que no banco ta sendo salvo assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será que tem alguma coisa a ver?
Alguém saberia o que pode estar causando isso ou como me ajudar concertar?
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: ASP.NET com evento de click?

Comment: isso mesmo segue o aspx

Comment: <div style="margin: 60px 0 5px 600px;">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSalvarImovel" runat="server" Text="Salvar" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClick="btnSalvarImovel_Click" accept="image/jpeg" />
            </div>

Comment: Se fez upload da mesma imagem várias vezes deve ser normal o servidor dar nomes diferentes, de forma a que nenhuma imagem seja apagada. Tente dar um nome único para o ficheiro.

Comment: Oi Bruno, obrigada por responder, editei a pergunta pra ficar um pouco melhor de entender o que esta acontecendo. As fotos tem um nome único cada uma, o que acontece é que ao salvar ela pega a primeira que foi selecionada e meio que substitui o conteúdo da foto, deixando intacto apenas o nome delas